# Как определить потребность функции в стеке

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, arm

Как определить потребность нерекурсивной функции в стеке при помощи *arm-none-eabi*?

Comment: В смысле на какое максимальное значение байтов может увеличиться стек за время работы функции?

Comment: Да, конечно. Это очень важная хактеристика для малых систем.

Comment: -fstack-usage пробовали?

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я этот ключик, почему то, не смог отискать.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian может оформить как ответ, если решает проблему ТС?

Comment: @alexolut короткий будет наверное слишком, может вы попробуете?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian не хочу за чужую идею баллы получать :) главное чтоб на минимальное кол-во символов набралось для публикации и решало проблему, остальное не важно.

Comment: Этот ключ есть в списке `g++ --help=common`. Просто я не увидел. Если у вас есть желание, можете написать об этом, и о контроле границ стека за одно.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ключ `-fstack-usage` должен помочь. Цитата из [документации](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Static-Stack-Usage-Analysis.html):

> A unit compiled with -fstack-usage will generate an extra file that
>   specifies the maximum amount of stack used, on a per-function basis.
>   The file has the same basename as the target object file with a .su
>   extension. Each line of this file is made up of three fields:
>
> - The name of the function.
> - A number of bytes.
> - One or more qualifiers: static, dynamic, bounded.

На выходе получите файлы с расширением .su, где на каждой линии будет имя функции, число байтов и один или несколько квалификаторов (static, dynamic, bounded и т.д.).

Аналогичный ответ на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6390984/5011111).